# Sikuli - How to identify unique or random web elements

Tags: selenium, sikuli

I have setup Sikuli with selenium and Java. I can click and navigate on screens.
On my current screen, the element I want to identify changes each time I run the script)(You can basically see it as a random number).

I want to identify the random number and then write it a log file.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Use element screenshot to find the element from the whole screen is Sikuli basic find element strategy.  If the number displayed on the element is random,  i think it's no way.  Why use Sikuli for web automation, selenium can't meet your requirement.

Comment: Selenium doesn't see the xpath as it in flash. I know Sikuli is using image recognition, so that challenge is how do you handle labels that change constantly for example if you create a client, every time the client will have an unique number on the screen. I'm curious how will Sikuli handle these situations. I will have a look  as the solutions posted and provide feedback very soon. Thanks for all the comments and answers.

Comment: Maybe you can define the region where the text is in (and where it also changes and then use `Region text()` to extract the tekst.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try double clicking on the text and then use ctrl c, ctrl v to store this from the clipboard to a variable.

2) Try mouse drag to select the text and use copy paste to store this in a variable.

3) You can use selenium along with sikuli. This way you have both tools to play with such scenarios.